Show that the conformally complete Schwarzschild spacetime is asymptotically flat at null infinity
I am trying to show that the conformal factor  used to conformally complete the
Schwarzschild spacetime renders it asymptotically flat at null infinity (according to the mathematical definition given in Definition 10.2 here https://radbouduniversitypress.nl/site/books/m/10.54195/EFVF4478/). For that I am checking  the three properties given there

condition 2: Since the Ricci tensor is 0, this is trivially satisfied
I am having trouble with the other conditions,
condition 1: How do I get the expresion for a function from say $\mathcal{I}^+\to \Bbb R \times S^2 $ such that I can check that I indeed have a diffeomorphism?
condition 3
What does "ruling " even mean to start with? I guess it means the geodesics contained in there? How do I prove that the lightlike geodesics ruling $\mathcal{I}^{\pm}$ are complete?
I have to start by checking that the condition $\hat \Delta \Omega=0 $ is satisfied. How do I do that? I am not sure how to deal with the $\hat \nabla$, if I just ignore the hat I still have the problem that $\Omega $ is given by a rather complicated expresion, so I am not sure how to deal with the fucntions of P and Q to compute $\hat \Delta \Omega=0 $ given in eq 10.76

Any help is appreaciated
